# How do i run a tkinter form without focus?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can i run a tkinter application that doesn't take the focus but remains always on top?

I'm using a library that inputs characters as if they were input from the keyboard, and i want to build a tkinter application that shows the user a variety of characters (a virtual keyboard), but in order to input the characters the application of interest must have the focus, and i want the virtual keyboard to remain on the top (without taking the focus).

Here's what i've tried, in this code i minimize the window before writing the character, so the application of interest is focused when the character is written, after that i show the window again:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import tkinter as tk
import time

keyboard = Controller()

########################################################################
class MyApp(object):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        self.root = parent
        self.root.title("Special Characters")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.bind("<Enter>", self.onHover)
        self.frame.pack()

        btn01 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="á", command=lambda: self.printChar('á')).grid(row=0,column=0)
        btn02 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="é", command=lambda: self.printChar('é')).grid(row=0,column=1)
        btn03 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="í", command=lambda: self.printChar('í')).grid(row=0,column=2)
        btn04 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="ó", command=lambda: self.printChar('ó')).grid(row=1,column=0)
        btn05 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="ú", command=lambda: self.printChar('ú')).grid(row=1,column=1)
        btn06 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="ñ", command=lambda: self.printChar('ñ')).grid(row=1,column=2)
        btn07 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Á", command=lambda: self.printChar('Á')).grid(row=2,column=0)
        btn08 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="É", command=lambda: self.printChar('É')).grid(row=2,column=1)
        btn09 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Í", command=lambda: self.printChar('Í')).grid(row=2,column=2)
        btn10 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Ó", command=lambda: self.printChar('Ó')).grid(row=3,column=0)
        btn11 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Ú", command=lambda: self.printChar('Ú')).grid(row=3,column=1)
        btn12 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Ñ", command=lambda: self.printChar('Ñ')).grid(row=3,column=2)

        btnClose = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Close", command=self.closeWindow).grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=3,rowspan=1)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def onHover(self, event):
        self.root.focus_force()

    def printChar(self, character):
        """"""
        self.root.withdraw()

        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press(character)
        keyboard.release(character)
        time.sleep(0.1)

        self.root.deiconify()

    def closeWindow(self):
        self.root.destroy()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `root.attributes("-topmost", True)`?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: I'm using pynput to emulate character input, in order to focus on the application of interest i hide the window, wait for 1/10 secconds, write the character, wait other 1/10 secconds and finally show the window again, i'm going to upload the code i'm using after work

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to create a `Toplevel` widget without immediately switching over to this new `Toplevel` widget being the focus?

Comment: exactly, what i'm doing right now is hiding my program temporarily, so the application where i want to write is at focus when my (now hidden) program inserts the character, after that i restore the program, which doesn't make it unusable, but when the program is restored it resets its position on the screen, and it seems broken every time it hides and restores